# UITableview slow scrolling, or mismatched cell position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My `UITableView`, when scrolling is lagging. This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CellListsFriend *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellListsFriend" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell.selected) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    ContactAlphaB *contact = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableAttributedString *strFullname;
    if (strFullname == nil) {
        strFullname = [NSString DrawColorForFullname_firstName:contact.firstName lastName:contact.lastName];
    }
    cell.lblNameFriend.attributedText = strFullname;
    cell.lblStatusSentense.text = contact.usernameIsUsing;
    [cell.lblStatusSentense setTextColor:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:color_status_ShowUser]];
    if ([contact.registerType isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        cell.lblRegisterType.text = @"Email";
    }
    else{
        cell.lblRegisterType.text = @"Mobile";
    }
    [NSURLConnection getImage:contact.linkAvatar showImage:cell.imgAvatarFriends];
    [cell.lblRegisterType setTextColor:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:@"777777"]];
    // Rounded Rect for cell image
    cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderWidth=2;
    cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imgAvatarFriends.frame.size.width/2];
    [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    return cell;
}
```

My methods get image from document direction:

```
+(UIImageView *)getImage:(NSString*)strImageName showImage:(UIImageView*)showImage{
    NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strImageName];
    NSArray *arrayPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                        NSDocumentDirectory,
                                        NSUserDomainMask,
                                        YES);
    NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    showImage.image = image1;
    return showImage;
}
```

I have researcheed and use:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
```

My code is already edited like below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CellListsFriend *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellListsFriend" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ContactAlphaB *contact = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.lblRegisterType setTextColor:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:@"777777"]];
    NSString *strNameImg = contact.linkAvatar;
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
//        [NSURLConnection getImage:strNameImg showImage:cell.imgAvatarFriends];
        cell.lblNameFriend.attributedText = [NSString DrawColorForFullname_firstName:contact.firstName lastName:contact.lastName];
        cell.lblStatusSentense.text = contact.usernameIsUsing;
        [cell.lblStatusSentense setTextColor:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:color_status_ShowUser]];
        if ([contact.registerType isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            cell.lblRegisterType.text = @"Email";
        }
        else{
            cell.lblRegisterType.text = @"Mobile";
        }
        NSArray *arrayPaths =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                            NSDocumentDirectory,
                                            NSUserDomainMask,
                                            YES);
        NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:strNameImg];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        cell.imgAvatarFriends.image = image1;
    });
    // Rounded Rect for cell image
    cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderWidth=2;
    cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imgAvatarFriends.frame.size.width/2];
    [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    return cell;
}
```

It does not lag, but it moves the position of the cell. How to I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112166/slow-uitableview-scrolling

Comment: You're doing so much stuff inside cellForRowAtIndexPath! The layer properties (rounded rect) will slow the scrolling down. I can imagine data jumping around because you're using an async method and aren't cancelling it before calling it again. Preload the data and use the loaded data inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. And move the cell logic into your CellListsFriend class.

Comment: How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    cell.lblNameFriend.attributedText...
    etc.
}
```

**Risky**

looks really dangerous: you are basically changing the content of a cell **after** the facts. The very cell you are modifying may not be the original one, it may have been reused already. This approach would work if you were not using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, essentially allowing the system to cache the cells, and, as aptly named, recycle them.

**Safe**

The proper method is close to, but not exactly identical to what you are doing. You can keep taking advantage of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, but you need to trigger a reload cell when the data (images, etc) is available.

In other words, when you return a cell from:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

you may not keep a pointer to that cell for later use. You may, however, ask the system to redraw that very cell an many time as needed, when data becomes available.